# Laravel: insert null into boolean column that is nullable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a boolean column that is nullable created in Laravel using

```
$table->boolean('colName')->nullable();
```

The issue I am having is I want to insert a null value into it.

But as far as I know, if you assign null (using Eloquent's create or update), php will evaluate null to false, thus assigning 0 (false) into the column instead.

```
$toInsert = null;
```

This doesn't work.

How I use my code

First I get the input from form

```
$nullableVal = $request->input('nullable-value');

if($nullableVal == "yes"){
    $toInsert = true;
}else if($nullableVal == "no"){
    $toInsert = false;
}else{
    $toInsert = null;
}
```

My store/update via eloquent

```
$this->repository->update(['nullableVal' => $toInsert]);
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why not cast it then? `(bool) $toInsert` although this will insert as false and not null. If you want it to be null, just do not insert anything. `if(!is_null($toInsert)) ..`

Comment: if you assign null it will be null, have you tested it ? is this all assumptions ? How is the code used to assign the null value ? add it to your question.

Comment: @N69S It is tested yes. I will update my post but here is the gist: I receive an input from a form. This form is a select with three options: yes, no, not required. Then before storing/updating, I have a if else that checks where the input is a yes, no or not required. Yes = true, no = false, not required = null. Despite the null assignment, it evaluates to false.

Comment: @very_naisu The code inside your "repository" update method is changing the null to something else (or ignoring the update) check it. Just for general info, PHP doesnt change value like null to zero on a wimp and without reason. it's when you cast it as a boolean that the change happen. like when you do `if (null)` it will be considered as `if(false)`

Comment: @N69S I'll check my code out again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the field is nullable, it's default value should be `NULL`, right? In that case, just remove the `else` case.

```php
$model = new Model;

if ($nullableVal == "yes") {
    $model->colName = true;
} elseif ($nullableVal == "no") {
    $model->colName = false;
}

$model->save();
```

If `$nullableVal` is neither 'yes' or 'no', then colName won't be set and therefore, become NULL in the database.

Comment: doesnt work if it's an update.

Comment: explicitly setting to null should work, but you say it doesnt. Maybe you have an event or some database trigger that casts the value to boolean?

Answer (score 0):

if migration has `nullable()` than by default it is already `NULL` in database

By default make `$toInsert` `NULL`

```php
$nullableVal = $request->input('nullable-value');

$toInsert = NULL;

if($nullableVal == "yes"){
  $toInsert = true;
}

$this->repository->update(['nullableVal' => $toInsert]);
```